# Raid 1 / Raid 10 - Disk Failure

Tags: linux, centos, raid, software-raid

I have setup Software Raid 1 and Raid 10 using VirtualBox for testing purpose.

The partition and raid setup look like this:

[image]

When I deliberately remove Disk2 and restart a server, it booted to OS fine but it didn't let me know there was a disk failure?

Comment: Use `cat /proc/mdstat` to check Linux software raid status.

Answer (score 2):

In a production environment you would probably have a number of ways of being alerted of this.  For example,

1. A monitoring system like nagios running scripts to look at `/proc/mdstat` and/or various outputs of `mdadm`.
2. A log collector reading in the contents of `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/dmesg`, etc.
3. SNMPd running with a trap target configured.  I don't know if `md` sends traps or not, though.
4. Hardware out-of-band management devices like Dell's iDRAC, configured to send traps or emails on hardware failure.

And, yes, all of these wonderful things can be configured to page you at 2 AM! :-)